# Permissions on sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have accidentally deleted all the permissions on a specific lists and libraries page in sharepoint, I need to get access to this page again. How can i do this?

I am using sharepoint 2010

Comment: How have you "deleted all the permissions" and what exactly is a "lists and libraries page"?

Answer (score 1):

Get in touch with the Site Collection Administrator and ask them to set the permissions of the page/list/library to inherit from the parent site.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Permissions for this document library**  under List setting of those specific lists and libraries and click on Inherit Permission from the ribbon. These will get you the parent site permission in the list .

If the list and libraries were having unique permission then buddy u better run :)...

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned lists & libraries, more than one... so affected is whole web or site collection?

Ask for a backup from pervious day, restored in some demo/test environment. Check original permission settings on recovered collection / affected objects and ask your Site Collection admin to set them back again. Or ask SharePoint admin to give you Site Collection admin rights to set them back by yourself. It is not good to inherit everything from the top if you are not 100% sure, that there is no file or page with confidential content (salary tables, product release tables, legal claims, bonuses... etc.) or special setup (unique rights) inside.

If you have no backup or if affected object is one list or library only and restoring is time-consuming, still you need to find someone, who acting like web / collection admin to give you rights back (probably based on configuration of parent site).